# Execute a function on every iteration/tick of event loop

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

The title said it all. I have a function `foo() { console.log("foo"); }`. How can I make sure that each event loop iteration will execute my function once?

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What is this "tick" you're talking about? http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D

Comment: Well the `tick` or `iteration` is defined as: `the synchronous invocation of zero or more callback functions associated with any external events. Once the queue is emptied out and the last function returns, the tick is over. We go back to the beginning (the next tick) and check for events that were added to the queue from other threads while our JavaScript was running`

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you can add it to the event loop using `setInterval(foo)` [see zero delays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Zero_delays)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn `setInterval(foo)` schedules macrotask and this is unreliable because sometimes event loop just spends 1 or 2 or more iterations to do something else like calling RAF

Comment: @meteorzero it is still added to the event loop, and will not necessarily execute in the number of milliseconds that is given as parameter two if there are still items waiting to be processed in the event loop. It is however, the closest that you will get to executing on every iteration.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I got a task to count how many event loop iterations have occurred in 5 seconds of idle browser (task queue empty, job queue empty, no input, nothing at all). Do you know how to count?